# How to prevent #Error values derived from Nulls in an outer join

Tags: ms-access, null, error-handling, join, ms-access-2010

Suppose I have two tables to outer join

```
Tab1:
ID  Nam
1   Joe
2   Moe
3   Flo

Tab2:
ID  Val     y   w
1   stuff   66  33
2   duff    67  44
```

and one of the resulting columns is derived -- i.e., it's a function of two other columns

```
SELECT Tab1.*, Tab2.Val, Tab2.y, Tab2.w, week(Tab2.y,Tab2.w) AS week
FROM Tab1 LEFT JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.ID = Tab2.ID
```

As expected, where there is no join, nulls appear under the actual columns, but `#Error` appears under the *derived* column:

```
ID  Nam Val     y   w   week
1   Joe stuff   66  33  66w33
2   Moe duff    67  44  67w44
3   Flo                 #Error
```

First, I thought I could prevent `#Error` via the useful-for-handling-null-strings function `Nz()` but `Nz(week(Tab2.y,Tab2.w))` did nothing.
Next, I thought it was something I had to handle in my `week()` function -- i.e., handle cases of `IsNull(y)` -- but I discovered that it doesn't even get called for the "null cases".

How to prevent `#Error` values from showing?

Comment: Use `week(Tab2.y, Nz(Tab2.w, ValueYouWantInstead))` You need to apply the function that replaces the null with another value before the function call.

Comment: It worked, @ypercube! At least, i no longer get `#Error`. I got `0w00` which I did have to handle in my function: `if y=0 ...` Care to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: What does this function (week) do? Simple concatenation? Can't you use `Nz(Tab2.y, '0') & 'w' & Nz(Tab2.w, '00') AS week` ?

Comment: @ypercube - That's more or less what it does. I use it in a few places so i'd rather keep it as a function -- unless there's good reason not to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the function (`Nz`) that replaces the null with another value *before* the `week` function call. Use:

```
week( Nz(Tab2.y, Value_for_y) , Nz(Tab2.w, Value_for_w) )
```

You probably also need tests against the special `Value_for_y` or `Value_for_w` inside `week()`.